# Is there a tool that checks what predefined macros a C file depends on?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, static-analysis

To avoid impossible situation one could reduce the problem to two cases.

**Case 1**

The first (simplest) case is situation where the preprocessor has a chance to detect it, that is there's a preprocessor directive that depends on a macro being predefined (that is defined before the first line of input) or not. For example:

```
#ifdef FOO
#define BAR 42
#else
#define BAR 43
#endif
```

depends on `FOO` being predefined or not. However the file

```
#undef FOO

#ifdef FOO
#define BAR 42
#endif
```

does not. A harder case would be to detect if the dependency actually does matter, which it doesn't in the above cases (as neither `FOO` or `BAR` affects the output).

---

**Case 2**

The second (harder) case is where successful compilation depends on predefined macros:

```
INLINE int fubar(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

which is perfectly fine as far as the preprocessor is concerned whether or not `ENTRY_POINT` is predefined, but unless `INLINE` is carefully defined that code won't compile. Similarily we could in this case it might be possible to exclude cases where the output isn't affected, but I can't find an example of that. The complication here is that in the example:

```
int fubar(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

the `fubar` being predefined can alter the successful compilation of this, so one would probably need to restrict it to cases where a symbol need to be predefined in order to compile successfully.

---

I guess such a tool would be something similar to a preprocessor (and C parser in the second case). The question is if there is such a tool? Or is there a tool that only handles the first case? Or none at all?

Comment: Tool-recs are off topic, in general, you know that, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is not about recommendation of a tool, but rather existence of it (but of course to support an affirmative answer an example might have to be given).

Comment: For those who recommended to close this as being a tool-rec question: for this to be a tool-rec question there would need to be at least **two** such tools (which would answer the question). If there's only one such tool there would be not much of a recommendation and if there's no such tool which one would you recommend? Do you still think you have support for your claim that this is a tool-rec question? If you do, then I would like to see them as it would answer the question.

Comment: Everything that has an identifier in it depends on that identifier being predefined as a macro or not (unless it's first seen in an undef or define directive).  Your example depends not only on `INLINE`, but also on `int`, `fubar`, `void`, and `return`.

Comment: C compilers are the closest real-world alternatives, because compilation failures *typically* occur near the macros with missing definitions. You could probably add some kind of error-checking program that finds macro-looking tokens near errors reported by the compiler. However, none of those help if a missing macro definition causes valid, but logically incorrect, code to be generated. The solution to the underlying problem is, as usual, **documentation**, and not some automagic tool. In this case, one block of informative comments near the beginning of the source file(s) would do nicely.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, the second case opens up for that. Defining `fubar` as `@` would result in invalid output and strictly speaking the code depends on `fubar` not being defined or suitably defined. A useful tool would not trigger on this, but the question is more directed at macros that **need** to be defined in order to make the output valid. I've updated the question to address this.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Do you think that the compiler would do that in the first example would complain. I've updated it so that it would not complain even if we later use `BAR`. So in that case a compiler would not result in compilation failure. I don't think that scenario is non-typical at all, it's actually the typical scenario where such a tool would be used.

Comment: Deciding on a minimal set of changes that turns an arbitrary text into a valid C program is an intractable problem.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it's probably a hard problem, but I don't think it's an impossible problem at least. If the problem is hard enough one would not expect there to be a tool that addresses the second case.

Comment: I have no idea what the second case is, you have not numbered them. As I read your post, all of your proposed tools are either trivial or impossible.

Comment: @n.m. I've edited to make more clear which the two cases are. If you think that the second case is outright impossible then of course a tool covering that shouldn't exist. I don't expect a tool to exist covering that case to exist if it's an hard enough problem or if the result becomes too complex to grasp (even if it's theoretically possible).

Comment: @skyking: My point is, you're looking for a hammer that has a small head in the center of the hitting face, so it can be used with screws. In other words, it is a technically interesting question, but you wouldn't actually use such tools in real life, because the underlying question is much better solved by proper documentation rather than any tool. This is why I do not think there is such a tool -- they only tend to be created when someone wants to use one. You can create one for at least limited cases (as shown), but why would you? Use a proper tool for the job, instead: documentation.

Comment: @NominalAnimal In an ideal world the documentation would do the trick. But we don't live in an ideal world: the problem is (in reality) the documentation is often missing, incomplete or outright wrong (especially if it's legacy code).

Comment: @skyking: I know. The only solution I see is taking the time to pore over the code, until one understands it well enough to document the intent and expectations. For this kind of situation, I just cannot see any automagic tool to help. I don't intend to discourage you in any way, either; it's just that this particular problem is best solved by human (or any other sentient) programmer.

Comment: @NominalAnimal For smaller codebase it may work, but otherwise I disagree. Sooner or later when reading through the code you will become a "zombie", you will work much like a computer program except you will be more prone to mistakes. I think SW development tools that relieves humans from such tasks are useful.

Comment: @skyking: Tools are needed and useful for mechanical tasks, yes, but you cannot substitute tools for *cognition*. Only a mind of a programmer can comprehend the *intent* of the code; no tool can excavate it from written code, because the code rarely reflects the underlying intent. Fortunately, there are lots of tools that help one with that (but are nothing like what you are looking for here): for example, those that make easy cross-references across a project. To avoid zombification, you just need to pace and focus yourself, just like in every other profession.

Answer (score 1):

In C everything can be (re)defined, so there is no way to know in advance what is intended to be (re)defined. Usually some naming conventions helps us to figure out what is meant to be a macro (like upper-case). Therefore it is not possible to have such tool. Of course if you assume that the compilation errors are caused by missing macro definitions then you can use them to analyze what is missing.